# How to use an awk variable from another file

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files:

- File1 containing latitude, longitude, altitude and percentage change in a parameter
- File2 containing altitude and average absolute parameter.

File1

```
89.0 -179.0 40.0 -1.9290
89.0 -179.0 50.0 -1.7720
89.0 -179.0 70.0 -0.8970
89.0 -179.0 90.0 -0.4020
87.0 -179.0 40.0 -2.6490
87.0 -179.0 50.0 -2.4850
87.0 -179.0 70.0 -1.5370
87.0 -179.0 90.0 -0.7770
85.0 -179.0 40.0 -2.0090
85.0 -179.0 50.0 -1.8270
85.0 -179.0 70.0 -1.2930
85.0 -179.0 90.0 -0.5480
83.0 -179.0 40.0 -0.6930
83.0 -179.0 50.0 -0.4000
83.0 -179.0 70.0 -0.1050
83.0 -179.0 90.0 0.1200
81.0 -179.0 40.0 -0.3000
81.0 -179.0 50.0 -0.0780
81.0 -179.0 70.0 0.1760
81.0 -179.0 90.0 0.1430
```

File2

```
40.0000000       4.3764738518518698
50.0000000       4.3796847037037017
70.0000000       4.3780389444444472
90.0000000       4.3688861728394963
```

Now, I need to create a file with latitude, longitude, altitude and absolute parameter. Basically I need to change p into p(1+a/100), where p is the average parameter and a is the percentage change. The resultant file will look like this:

```
 89.0 -179.0 40.0 4.2920516
```

I can use do while loop or any other loop to do this but is time consuming for a large file. I believe there is a one-liner awk that I am not able to figure out.

I tried

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}{$4=a[FNR]*(1+$4/100)}1' file2 file1
```

But this one works only when the order of altitude is same in both the files and if both files have equal number of lines.

I want to search for the altitude in the first file, take the corresponding average parameter and use it as a variable for the second file. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can force numerical comparison with `+0`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR  {a[$1+0]=$2; next} 
       $3+0 in a{$4=a[$3+0]*(1+$4/100)}1' file2 file1

89.0 -179.0 40.0 4.29205
89.0 -179.0 50.0 4.30208
89.0 -179.0 70.0 4.33877
89.0 -179.0 90.0 4.35132
87.0 -179.0 40.0 4.26054
87.0 -179.0 50.0 4.27085
87.0 -179.0 70.0 4.31075
87.0 -179.0 90.0 4.33494
85.0 -179.0 40.0 4.28855
85.0 -179.0 50.0 4.29967
85.0 -179.0 70.0 4.32143
85.0 -179.0 90.0 4.34494
83.0 -179.0 40.0 4.34614
83.0 -179.0 50.0 4.36217
83.0 -179.0 70.0 4.37344
83.0 -179.0 90.0 4.37413
81.0 -179.0 40.0 4.36334
81.0 -179.0 50.0 4.37627
81.0 -179.0 70.0 4.38574
81.0 -179.0 90.0 4.37513
```

Comment: what does a{...} mean? Is it a sequence?

Comment: It's the statement that runs if the prior condition is true. `$3 in a`